# JavaScript error, missing a ``)`` but when it is added ``Unexpected end of input``? - Help Needed

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Hello (I am very new to programming!)

I keep getting this error message (below) whenever I try to run my bot in CMD.
(Scroll down for code and error and stuff) I am super confused about all of this!

I tried fixing it by removing the `;` but that didn't work, it told me the `)` was unexpected, but when I removed the `)` it told me it was needed!

Code Block One:

```js
// Runs on bot start
bot.on('ready', () => {

  // Now we post into the console that the  bot has been turned on.
  console.log('Bot turned on in the CMD')
});
```

Code Block Two: (Semi-Colon Removed)

```js
// Runs on bot start
bot.on('ready', () => {

  // Now we post into the console that the  bot has been turned on.
  console.log('Bot turned on in the CMD')
})
```

Code Block Three:

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {

  // Now we post into the console that the  bot has been turned on.
  console.log('Bot turned on in the CMD')
}
```

Expected  Result:
Bot turns on, sends a message in the CMD to that effect.

```
Error #1 (See code block 1 to find the code)
`C:\Users\xgoul\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\app.js:74
});
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)`
Error #2 (See code block 2 to find the code)
`C:\Users\xgoul\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\app.js:74
})
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)`
Error #3 (See code block 3 to find the code)
`C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\app.js:74
}
^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)`
```

Comment: Apologies that That all the errors and code blocks are, for some reason, smaller than "Code Block 1" while the other code blocks are small

Answer (score 0):

Code block 1 is correct, its returning unexpected end of input because you have to include a return statement.

```
// Runs on bot start
bot.on('ready', () => {

  // Now we post into the console that the  bot has been turned on.
  console.log('Bot turned on in the CMD');
  return('whatever');
});
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem post the rest of your code, it may be from something else

Comment: Just to elaborate on this, you've probably seen something similar:

`bot.on('ready', () => 

  console.log('Bot turned on in the CMD')
);`
Where the difference is adding the curly braces requires a return, while not having them is a shortcut that implies whatever the contents of the function evaluates to is the return value.